# ReactJS Tooltip for Help Icon

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I have added a help icon on my react text area and now I need to add a tool tip to give hint for the text area. Below is my code snippet

```
<div
    style={{
        paddingLeft: '5px',
        paddingRight: '5px'
    }}>

    <div style={{ position: "absolute", width: "94%" }}>   <textarea
        placeholder="Pre-Requisites"
        name="preRequisites"
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        value={this.state.preRequisites}
        style={style.textAreaStyle} />
    </div>
    <div data-tip data-for='happyFace'>
        <MdHelp data-tip data-for='happyFace' style={style.helpIconStyle} />
    </div>
    <ReactTooltip id='happyFace' type='error'>
        <span>My Tool</span>
    </ReactTooltip>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot of my textarea with help icon on it,[image]

Can anyone help me to add a tooltip which shows some message on the help icon.

Comment: Checked any existing react tooltip components available in npm?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to create a component or use a module from npm, you could use [html](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) title attribute :

Definition :

> The title attribute specifies extra information about an element.

```
<textarea title="amazing textarea"> Hello i'm a textarea </textarea>
<span title="amazing span"> Hello i'm a span </span >
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change `position:"relative"` in your `textarea style`